# Pi Power Distribution - how much needed

Tags: power, cable

I was using my Pi (1 model B+) in order to create a remote controlled car (Another question I have about that I posted). The issue is that when I connected the 9v battery to power my wheels, it absolutely murdered my Pi and now it won't turn on.

I have another Pi, but to make sure the issue doesn't happen again, how should I reduce the power? Should I not use a power cable, or use some resistors?

Comment: what  kind of a 9V battery? ..... how did you connect it? .......... you will have to provide a detailed description of how you connected the failed RPi before we can determine why it failed and provide suggestions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You killed your Pi by feeding it 9 Volts. The Pi is 5 Volts maximum.

You need a step down regulator or buck converter to convert 9 Volts down to 5 Volts. Depending on the Pi you use check how many amps you require.

https://www.pololu.com/product/2831

https://www.adafruit.com/product/1385